# How can I test if a column exists in a table using an SQL statement

Tags: postgresql, information-schema

Is there a simple alternative in PostgreSQL to this statement produced in Oracle?

```
select table_name from user_tab_columns
where table_name = myTable and column_name = myColumn;
```

I am then testing whether the query returns anything so as to prove the column exists.

I am aware that using psql I can find these out individually but this is required to produce a result in a program I am writing to validate that a requested attribute field exists in my database table.

Answer (score 152, accepted):

Try this :

```
SELECT column_name 
FROM information_schema.columns 
WHERE table_name='your_table' and column_name='your_column';
```

Comment: Thanks. Accepted as answer as it is a direct alternative to what I was doing in Oracle.

Comment: @CSharpened what is the query for Oracle?

Comment: This is an *extremely* fragile answer - e.g,. if a table called `your_table` appears in a `schema` that is higher up in `search_path`. My PostGIS database has monthly schema, each with identical table names; using this answer, `vicmap201208.address` would be found before `vicmap201910.address` because `vicmap201208` appears before `vicmap201910` on `search_path` (for good reasons that I wouldn't want to change just to make a bad answer work). [As it happens, the column names are constant across schemas: that's not the point]

Answer (score 58):

Accepted answer is correct, but is missing the schema and nicer output (True/False):

```
SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
FROM information_schema.columns 
WHERE table_schema='my_schema' AND table_name='my_table' AND column_name='my_column');
```

Comment: Also takes in account the schema

Comment: Or just 
`SELECT true as exists FROM information_schema.columns WHERE ...;`

Answer (score 26):

Simpler and SQLi-safe using PostgreSQL's [object identifier types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-oid.html):

```sql
SELECT true
FROM   pg_attribute 
WHERE  attrelid = 'myTable'::regclass  -- cast to a registered class (table)
AND    attname = 'myColumn'
AND    NOT attisdropped  -- exclude dropped (dead) columns
-- AND attnum > 0        -- exclude system columns (you may or may not want this)
```

System catalogs are many times faster than querying the notoriously convoluted `information_schema` (but still just milliseconds for a single query). See:

- [Get column names and data types of a query, table or view](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/75124/3684)

Read about the [significance of the columns in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-attribute.html).

While building dynamic SQL with the column name supplied as parameter, use [`quote_ident()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) to defend against SQL injection:

```
...
AND    attname = quote_ident('myColumn');
```

Works for tables outside the `search_path`, too:

```
...
WHERE  attrelid = 'mySchema.myTable'::regclass
...
```

Answer (score 5):

Unlike Oracle, PostgreSQL supports the ANSI standard `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` views.

The corresponding standard view to Oracle's user_tab_columns is `information_schema.columns`

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/infoschema-columns.html

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT attname 
FROM pg_attribute 
WHERE attrelid = (SELECT oid FROM pg_class WHERE relname = 'YOURTABLENAME') 
AND attname = 'YOURCOLUMNNAME';
```

*Of course, replace **YOURTABLENAME** and **YOURCOLUMNNAME** with the proper values. If a row is returned, a column with that name exists, otherwise it does not.*

Comment: Thanks for the response. Although your example works fine I have opted to accept Ramandeeps answer due to its simplicity and the fact that it seems a more direct alternative to my issue.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a similar variant of Erwin Brandstetter answer.
Here we check schema too in case we have similar tables in different schema.

```
SELECT TRUE FROM pg_attribute 
WHERE attrelid = (
    SELECT c.oid
    FROM pg_class c
    JOIN pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
    WHERE 
        n.nspname = CURRENT_SCHEMA() 
        AND c.relname = 'YOURTABLENAME'
    )
AND attname = 'YOURCOLUMNNAME'
AND NOT attisdropped
AND attnum > 0
```