# PostgreSQL: skip erros in SQL clients using JDBC

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, squirrel-sql

I want to execute a SQL script in a client using JDBC (not the postgreSQL pslq client). In this script I would like to do something like that:

```
skip errors on;

alter table foo ...;

skip errors off;
```

Is there a way to do this with PostgreSQL >= 9.1?

Comment: Not like you describe. Just run one statement per transaction. If you can't do that, you need to use subtransactions in PL/PgSQL `DO` blocks.

Comment: So which SQL client is that?

Comment: I'm using SQuirreL or Flyway for sql code execution.

Comment: Does squirrel support using savepoints around statements? If yes, then enable that.

Comment: Thank's for your answers! One wish: Can someone please **rate my question/answer**? I need reputation to rate others here...:-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this thread with a good solution usind `DO` blocks and error codes: 
[How to continue sql script on error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24431174/how-to-continue-sql-script-on-error)

And creating a function for my problem:

```
create or replace function continueOnError(v_sqlStatement text)
  returns void
  language plpgsql
  as ' 
  BEGIN
    execute v_sqlStatement;
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN invalid_schema_name
      OR undefined_table 
      OR undefined_column 
    THEN RAISE WARNING ''Continued on error sql statement: %'', v_sqlStatement;
  END;
';
```

...use it:

```
select continueOnError('alter table test add constraint fk_test_valueid foreign key (valueid) references value(id)');
```