# update / exist column Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

i have a table `abonnement` with a column `topic` and other column. i want to update the value of the column `topic`. But before updating, i want to verify if this column exist or not to use this script with other developers in my team. If exist, I do update, else, i must to create this column and after do update.
Here is my script :

```
IF EXISTS (select topic from abonnement) 
then 
update abonnement set topic ='valeurTopic'; 
else 
ALTER TABLE abonnement ADD COLUMN topic character varying; 
update abonnement set topic= 'valeurTopic';
end if;
```

I had an error:

```
ERREUR:  erreur de syntaxe sur ou près de « IF »
LINE 1: IF EXISTS (SELECT topic
    ^
```

Any solution please ?

Comment: There is no `if` in SQL.

Comment: because i saw some script when they use 'if'. else, how i can resolve it ?

Comment: Rather then implementing workarounds like that, you should change the way you deploy schema changes. The fact that you don't know if the column exists or not _might_ indicate that you don't have a proper process to manage and deploy schema migrations. Check out tools like Liquibase or Flyway. Making sure the database is in a defined state is a much better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would change the logic:

```
DO $$ 
    BEGIN
        BEGIN
            ALTER TABLE <table_name> ADD COLUMN <column_name> <column_type>;
        EXCEPTION
            WHEN duplicate_column THEN 
            UPDATE <table_name> SET <column_name> = 'valeurTopic';
    END;
END; $$
```

I got the code from [How to add column if not exists on PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12597465/how-to-add-column-if-not-exists-on-postgresql)