# Redshift: add column if not exists

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, ddl

The following [works in Postgres 9.6](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38721951/1291563) but not in Redshift:

```
ALTER TABLE stats
    ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS panel_exit timestamp;
```

Can the same functionality be achieved in Redshift?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is no Amazon Redshift command equivalent to `ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS`.

See: [ALTER TABLE documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_ALTER_TABLE.html)

To replicate this functionality, your application would first need to query the table metadata and then make the decision whether to issue the `ADD COLUMN` command.

Answer (score 4):

John's answer set me in the right direction, here is the command I found best worked in Redshift to check for a column's existence.

```
SELECT EXISTS(
    SELECT * FROM pg_table_def
    WHERE schemaname = '<my_schema_name>'
    and tablename = '<my_table_name>'
    and "column" = '<my_column_name>'
);
```

Note the double quotes around "column" are required since `column` is also a keyword.

Additionally, if the table you are interested in is not in the `public` schema. You may need to first modify your search path so the results are returned as expected:

```
set SEARCH_PATH to <schema_name>;
```

See the [PG_TABLE_DEF AWS Docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_PG_TABLE_DEF.html) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

After much trial and error, this is one way in Redshift to add a new column if it does not exist.

Uses dynamic sql. Be sure to adjust your schema - I'm using `workdb`. There's prob enhancements one can make to this.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE workdb.add_column_if_not_exists(
    p_schema_name VARCHAR(256),
    p_table_name VARCHAR(256),
    p_column_name VARCHAR(256),
    p_column_data_type VARCHAR(256)
)
AS $$


BEGIN
    -- Check if the column exists
   RAISE NOTICE '***New Column Info***: %', p_schema_name;
   RAISE NOTICE 'p_schema: %', p_schema_name;
   RAISE NOTICE 'p_table_name: %', p_table_name;
   RAISE NOTICE 'p_column_name: %', p_column_name;
   RAISE NOTICE 'p_column_data_type: %', p_column_data_type;          
          
    IF ( select
        count(*)  cnt   
        from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
        where TABLE_SCHEMA = p_SCHEMA_NAME
            and TABLE_NAME = p_table_name
            and column_name = p_column_name
    ) = 0 THEN

          RAISE NOTICE 'Adding new column';
          EXECUTE 'ALTER TABLE ' || p_SCHEMA_NAME || '.' || p_table_name || ' ADD COLUMN ' || p_COLUMN_NAME || ' ' || p_COLUMN_DATA_TYPE;
          RAISE NOTICE 'New column Added';
    ELSE 
          RAISE NOTICE 'Column exists already';
    END IF;
   
END;

$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql
;
```

Then you can call it like this:

```
CALL workdb.add_column_if_not_exists('workdb', 'test_table', 'new_col', 'int');
```

Other examples here:

- [How to replicate IF NOT EXISTS in redshift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71622524/how-to-replicate-if-not-exists-in-redshift)